# Naming Convention for Methods and Properties in Swift. Can I use "get", "set" and "is" Keywords?

Tags: swift, naming-conventions

When I create a function in Swift, can I use "get" and "set" words? For instance can I declare a function as `func getAuthorizedUsers()` instead of `func authorizedUsers()`? In ObjectiveC get and set keywords are not suggested to use when declaring functions. How about in Swift?

Also, when declaring properties can I use "is" keyword? For instance:

```
public var isAuthorized: Bool {
    get {            
        return true
    }
}
```

I have read Swift naming convention documents but I couldn't find the answer of my question. Thank you.

Comment: You definitely want to check out this style guide... https://google.github.io/swift/

Comment: Why downgrade? I have seen lot's of sample swift code snippets including method names starting with get or set even in stack overflow. I don't think my question is useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules are all outlined [here](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines).

For `get`, that clearly violates the "Omit needless words" rule. If a method returns something, the call site will know that it is used to get some value. You don't need to repeat that idea. You can consider turning this into a computed property if no parameters are required.

For `set`, it might be appropriate sometimes. If your method only need one parameter and there is a corresponding getter,

```
func getFoo() -> Int {
    ...
}

func setFoo(_ foo: Int) {
    ...
}
```

That's a pretty good sign that this can be turned into a computed property:

```
var foo: Int {
    get { ... }
    set { ... }
}
```

A good example where it is appropriate to have `set` is the `UIButton.setTitle` method. It takes in two parameters, so a computed property wouldn't work.

For `is`, that clearly conforms to the rule "Uses of Boolean methods and properties should read as assertions about the receiver". So yes, you should use it for boolean members.